# WooCommerce "CONTACT" button when out of stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to achieve something that should be simple, but I've tried 3 approaches with multiple code variations and I just can't make it work. I'm trying to create a button that will appear in place of the "ADD TO CART" button on single product pages when the item is out of stock. Clicking the button will fire a popup contact form.

Is creating an add action in functions the right way to go, or should I replace the normal button with an if statement? I've tried both, so help with coding either would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's better to include the code you have tried, even if it doesn't work… This way you will avoid down votes or in the worst case to put this question `on-hold`. Also this way you will get better helped, as answerers will not try to use what you have tried yet. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can either hook into `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args` using a filter in your `functions.php` or edit the template file directly by pulling it into your theme. Either way will require a bit of PHP.

If doing it in your `functions.php`, it would look something like this (untested but should send you down the right path):

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'my_out_of_stock_button' );

function my_out_of_stock_button( $args ){
  global $product;
  if( $product && !$product->is_in_stock() ){
    return '<a href="' . home_url( 'contact' ) . '">Contact us</a>';
  }
  return $args;
}
```

I don't know what your button code should actually look like or what other information you need to capture, but this is how you could override the "Add to Cart" button and replace it if out of stock.

#### UPDATE

LoicTheAztec brought up a great point - the filter provided only affects the button on the archive, category, tag overview pages - not the individual product pages. There are no hooks for the individual product page buttons BUT you can [copy the templates to your theme and override them](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

You'll want to look at the files in `templates/single-product/add-to-cart`. Use a similar if statement as above:

```
#simple.php
<?php if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>
  // Standard WooCommerce code
<?php else: ?>
  // Your button code
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Just to say, `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` and  `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args` hooks only work on woocommerce archives pages and not in single product pages…

Comment: Amazing, works like a charm! Am I right, that I just need to go to my hosting 'mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php' and add there else statement? Will this code remain after woocommerce upgrade?

Comment: You’ll want to copy the file to your theme so it’s not overwritten when you update the plugin. Check out the link in the answer on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks! One more querstion, how to make the same for variations product? When I chose vatiations that are out of stock, there is still button add to cart

Comment: Check out the file at wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php - same idea - copy it to your theme and make your modification

Answer (score 2):

Just add below code in **functions.php** file of your **enabled theme** [reference](https://www.themelocation.com/replace-out-of-stock-with-contact-woo/)

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'themelocation_change_outofstock_to_contact_us', 1);
// for shop page 
function themelocation_change_outofstock_to_contact_us() {
  global $product;
  if (!$product->is_in_stock()) {
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
    //change the link to your contact us page
    echo '<a href="/contact"> Contact Us </a>';
  }
}
// for single page
add_filter('woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability($availability, $_product) {
  // Change In Stock Text
  if ($_product->is_in_stock()) {
    $availability['availability'] = __('Available!', 'woocommerce');
  }
  // Change Out of Stock Text
  if (!$_product->is_in_stock()) {
    $availability['availability'] = __('<a href="/contact"> Contact Us </a>', 'woocommerce');
  }
  return $availability;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to show a contact button on bespoke products and 
@ahwychkchih solution works great. One issue I had though is that schema markup will show as out of stock for those products which is not the case for beskpoke products is just they can't be purchased straight away so I've added this to force in_stock markup for my products. I'm aware that this solution would affect all products so you can always add a product id filter if needed

```
// Force In Stock schema markup
function fix_my_product_offers_schema ($markup_offer, $product) {
  if (!$product->is_in_stock()) {
        $markup_offer['availability'] = 'https://schema.org/InStock';
  }
  return $markup_offer;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_structured_data_product_offer', 'fix_my_product_offers_schema', 1, 2);
```